# Jquery UL Scroll 

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use Jquery to have scroll on a UL list, with two span to move up and down.
it works for one li child, but how for an ul filled dynamically ?
thank you, i'm totally lost

```
 $('span.scrollDown').click(function () {
        $('.liste-grostitres li:first-child').css('margin-top', 0 - $('.liste-grostitres li').outerHeight());
        $('.liste-grostitres').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });

    $('span.scrollUp').click(function () {
        $('.liste-grostitres li:first-child').css('margin-top', 0);
        $('.liste-grostitres').css('overflow', 'visible');
    });


<div id="grostitres">
    <div class="gInner">
    <span class="scrollUp"></span>
    <span class="scrollDown"></span>
    <div class="scrollable" id="divlist" runat="server">   
      <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          ...
      </ul>
    </div>              
    </div>
```

Comment: as you use jquery.. why not use jquery UI slider aswell? its one of the greatest things to have a dynamic customized scroller

Comment: i would like something like this :  http://portail.free.fr/ and that's i'm trying to do, but its a little complicated for me, i'm a beginner... i tried to use some plug in but well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heres a fiddle with slidetoggle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RMQLM/

also the working code example:

HTML:

```
<div id="up">up</div>
<div id="list">
<ul>
    <li>foo1</li>
    <li>bar1</li>
    <li>foo2</li>
    <li>bar2</li>
    <li>foo3</li>
    <li>bar3</li>
    <li>foo4</li>
    <li>bar4</li>
    <li>foo5</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="down">down</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#list {
    height: 93px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var listcount = $('li').size();
var cli = 1;
$('#down').click(function() {
    if (cli < listcount) {
        $('li:nth-child(' + cli + ')').slideToggle();
        cli++;
    }
});
$('#up').click(function() {
    if (cli > 1) {
        cli--;
        $('li:nth-child(' + cli + ')').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your UL to be `position: relative;` and have `top: 0;`.

Add a function to handle the animation:

```
var scroll_ul = function(offset) {
    // Target the UL to scroll
    var to_scroll = $('#divlist').find('ul');

    // Store the distance to scroll (assumes LIs are all equal height)
    var scroll_distance = $('#divlist').find('li').outerHeight(true);

    // Animate
    to_scroll.stop().animate({ top: '-=' + (offset * scroll_distance) });
};
```

Then change your click handlers to be something like this:

```
$('span.scrollDown').click(function() {
    scroll_ul(1);
});

$('span.scrollUp').click(function() {
    scroll_ul(-1);
});
```

You may experience strange scroll distances if you hammer the scrollDown/scrollUp buttons. That's when you should look into jQuery's `.one()` function.

Comment: Did you catch my latest edit? I was calling `scroll` instead of `scroll_ul` in the click handlers.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found an answer =)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more efficient to animate the whole UL instead of individual LIs. You already wrap the UL in a DIV, so why not animate the UL relative to the wrapper? That would work the same way as animating a single LI inside UL, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i display 5 li and I would like to move up and down, one li by one, with the span scrollup/down

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: like this it works well :   $('span.scrollDown').click(function () {
            $('.liste-grostitres').css('margin-top', 0 - $('.liste-grostitres li').outerHeight());
            $('.liste-grostitres').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        }); but only for one click, when i make another click, it doesnt work

Comment: See the other answer by mikos. ;)